# How do I byte-compile everything in my .emacs.d directory?

Tags: emacs, elisp, bytecode, dot-emacs

I have decided to check out Emacs, and I liked it very much. Now, I'm using the [Emacs Starter Kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/tree/master), which sort of provides better defaults and some nice customizations to default install of Emacs.

I have customized it a little, added some stuff like [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/), [color-themes](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/), [unbound](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/unbound.el), and other stuff. I've set up a [github repository](http://github.com/Irwin1138/emacs-starter-kit/tree/master) where I keep all of the customizations so I can access them from multiple places or in case something goes bad and I lose my .emacs.d directory.

All of this is very nice, but there is a problem: Emacs takes about 1-2 seconds to load. AFAIK I can compile individual .el files with M-x byte-compile-file to .elc, and it works. But there are a lot of .el files, and I wonder if there is a way to compile them all with a simple command or something, to speed up the loading of Emacs. My Emacs is not always open, and I open and close it quite frequently, especially after I've set it up as a default editor for edit command in Total Commander to get used to it faster (yeah, windows xp here).

My Emacs version is 22.3. And yes, the default Emacs installation without any customizations fires up instantly.

I am not sure which version is preferred when loading, the .el or compiled .elc one by the way O.o

So, is there an elisp command or Emacs command line switch to make Emacs byte-compile everything in .emacs.d directory?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

`C-u 0 M-x byte-recompile-directory`

will compile all the .el files in the directory and in all subdirectories below.

The `C-u 0` part is to make it not ask about every .el file that does not have a .elc counterpart.

Comment: And thereafter (once each has been compiled once), just use the same command without the `C-u 0` (aka `C-0`, BTW). That will byte-compile only those source files that are more recent than their byte-compiled versions.

Comment: A little note: for me that didn't worked until I removed all an according «.elc» files. It just told something like «Done, 0 files comiled, α files skipped».

Comment: @Hi-Angel  I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @zhanxw yep. Unfortunately the command compiles only files that either have changed, or have no «.elc» counterpart. So to recompile everything in a directory first you have to delete all «.elc» files.

Comment: The interactive command unfortunately doesn't expose it, but if you call the function directly you can use the optional argument `FORCE` to recompile files that already have an associated ".elc" even if they're not older than the source file: `M-: (byte-recompile-directory "/the/directory/" 0 t)`

Comment: You can also use the `byte-force-recompile` command to get the `FORCE` option.

Answer (score 51):

To automatically byte compile everything that needs byte compiling each time I start emacs, I put the following after my changes to `load-path` at the top of my `.emacs` file:

```
(byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d") 0)
```

Surprisingly, it doesn't add much to my startup time (unless something needs to be compiled).

To speed up my emacs, I first identified the slow parts using [profile-dotemacs.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProfileDotEmacs) and then replaced them with [autoloads](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).

Comment: [autoloads](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) documentation has moved.  That and the profile-dotemacs.el reference are exactly what I needed when I came across this page.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `--batch` flag to recompile from the command line.

To recompile all, do

```
emacs --batch --eval '(byte-recompile-directory "~/.emacs.d")'
```

or to recompile a single file as from a Makefile,

```
emacs --batch --eval '(byte-compile-file "your-elisp-file.el")'
```

Comment: use [batch-byte-compile](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compilation-Functions.html#index-batch_002dbyte_002dcompile-909) instead.

Comment: Could you should how to use it?

Comment: @nacho4d `emacs -Q --batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el foo/*.el` - it doesn't recurse like **byte-recompile-directory** does though.

Comment: You probably want to add an argument to force recompilation, eg.

emacs --batch --eval '(byte-recompile-directory "~/.emacs.d" 0)'

Answer (score 19):

This is swaying a bit from the question, but to solve the problem of loading slowly you can use the new daemon feature in Emacs 23.

> "If you have a lot of support packages,
>   emacs startup can be a bit slow.
>   However, emacs 23 brings emacs
>   --daemon, which enables you to start emacs in the background (for example
>   when you log in). You can instantly
>   pop up new emacs windows (frames) with
>   emacsclient. Of course, you could
>   already have an emacs 'server' in
>   older versions, but being able to
>   start it in the background makes this
>   a much nicer solution"

From http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/07/emacs-23-is-very-near.html

Comment: I definitely gonna check this one one out. Thank you!

Comment: If you add 
alias emacs='emacsclient -nw -a "" -c'
to your .bashrc (or your shell's version) it will first try to connect to a running daemon if there is one, if not it will start one and connect you.

Answer (score 3):

The command I use is `M-x byte-force-recompile RET`, it then asks the directory so, for example, I give it `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`. It then recompiles everything in there, usually no need to delete `.elc` files first or mess with it in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

For my using spacemacs, the command is `spacemacs/recompile-elpa`. The command `byte-recompile-directory` does not compile any file.

Comment: Different things. ELPA/MELPA stuff has defined build methods in its own archive hierarchy. byte-recompile-directory tries to compile all .el files in a user defined directory.